# :last-child style working, :first-child style not working! Why?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm creating an inset border effect between paragraphs by using a light border as the border-top on the paragraphs, and a dark border as the border bottom on them.

I'm trying to use p:first-child to remove the top border on the first paragraph, and p:last-child to remove the border on the bottom one. (they have a class of "intro" fyi).

The style to remove the bottom border on the :last-child is working properly, but for some reason the style to remove the top border on the :first-child is not.

It must be a typo or something silly because I can't figure out why it is working for the last-child but not the first-child.

http://joelglovier.com

markup:

```
<div id="intro">

    <div class="wrap">

        <h1 class="intro">Hi! I'm <a href="http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Joel+Andrew+Glovier">Joel Andrew Glovier</a></h1>

        <p class="intro">I'm a <a href="http://www.jagdesignideas.com/portfolio/web.html">web designer</a> and <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends">front-end developer</a>, currently working for <a href="http://cure.org">CURE International</a> full time. I also do some <a href="http://www.jagdesignideas.com">freelance work</a>, I <a href="http://twitter.com/jglovier">tweet a little</a>, <a href="http://www.jagdesignideas.com/blog/">blog</a> & can be found on <a href="http://jagdesignideas.com/contact.html">other social media</a>. I have <a href="http://dribbble.com/players/jag">lots of projects</a> going on at once - and I like it that way.</p>

        <p class="intro">I'm a <a href="/good-news">follower of Jesus</a>, and a proud father and husband. I'm also a <a href="http://www.google.com/images?q=bboy&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=univ&ei=dOpGTID9JoKKlwfV1vWfBA&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4&ved=0CDoQsAQwAw&biw=1920&bih=1102">bboy</a>, I <a href="http://jagboards.com/">skateboard</a>, and did I mention that I'm a die-hard <a href="http://www.steelers.com/">Pittsburgh Steelers</a> fan? Oh, and I've been to <a href="http://hmiafrica.org/">Kenya three times</a>.</p>

        <p class="intro">Well it's nice to meet you! now that you know so much about me, <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=@jglovier%20Hi%20Joel!" target="_blank">why don't you say hi</a>.</p>

    </div><!--/.wrap-->

</div>
```

CSS

```
div#intro p:first-child {
  border-top:none;
}
div#intro p:last-child {
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`p:first-child` does not work because the `h1` element is the first child of its corresponding parent element; the `p` elements are the second, third and fourth child elements. Use [`p:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) instead to only select the first element of the type `p`.

Comment: Isn't the `<div class="wrap">` the first child?

Comment: @animuson, the `:first-child` is applied to the `p` so it looks if it is the first child of the applied element parent..

Comment: I just wrapped the paragraphs in a span and targeted the span for :first-child instead of messing with :first-of-type. But thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: @animuson: Yes, that’s the first child of `#intro`. But here `:first-child` is tested for every `p` and `div#intro *:first-child` would match `#wrap` and the `h1` but not any `p`.