# first-child last-child and the ones in between

Tags: php, css, css-selectors

OK so I've got a PHP from that is propagated by a switch loop dependent on the dynamic case at hand (I think). Now, when I add in a checkbox, I want to be able to make the first check box in a `div` with a top border and sides, no bottom. The following ones just have a side border and the last to have sides and a bottom but no top. Hope this makes sense. This is all the code I have to edit:

```
case "E":
    $str.='<div id="leftcolrightboxcheckattach"><div id="enqattachcheckcontent" ><div id="enqleftcolattachcheckbox"><input type="checkbox" id="answer_question_'.$row['ques_id'].'[]" name="answer_question_'.$row['ques_id'].'[]" value="'.$arrMul[$i]["mul_name"].'" style="border:thick solid #fff" /></div><div id="enqleftcolattachcheckboxright">'.$arrMul[$i]["mul_name"].'</div></div></div>';
    break;
```

and here is my CSS. The standard class works, the `last-child` works but the `first-child` doesn't... any ideas why?

```
#leftcolrightboxcheckattach:first-child{width:96%; margin:5px auto; clear:both; background:#000; border-top:thin solid #E6E6E6;  position:relative; }
#leftcolrightboxcheckattach{width:96%; margin:5px auto; clear:both; background:#fff; border-left:thin solid #E6E6E6; border-right:thin solid #E6E6E6; position:relative; }
#leftcolrightboxcheckattach:last-child{width:96%; margin:5px auto; clear:both; background:#fff; border-bottom:thin solid #E6E6E6; position:relative; }
```

Comment: Because you overwritten it with middle rule, put first-child next to last-child.

Comment: Thought that but it doesnt make any difference first-child is still redundant.

Comment: Try using more narrow selector like `body #leftcolrightboxcheckattach:first-child`

Comment: Did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326480/last-child-style-working-first-child-style-not-working-why?rq=1 ?

Comment: Can you give us your HTML code for testing ( and /or a jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

```
#leftcolrightboxcheckattach:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
{

      .....
}
```